# I am using trying to use $modeswitch ISOIO with $mode objFPC. What ISO IO is enabled?

Tags: freepascal

I was looking for get and put to be available in ISOIO mode but they are not. What is enabled with ISOIO?

Comment: I updated the comment

Answer (score 0):

The details are undocumented, it seems like it mostly a subset of {$mode iso} for reading/writing files, that reroutes RTL handlers for reset/read/write to the ones for $mode ISO, and limits the types allowed for read/write in text mode.

It also enables look ahead with filetype^. (which is probably the reason why there are _ISO specific handlers in the first place, together with the ISO form of the RESET() statement) and variables
of ISO filetypes seem to be initialized. (under some circumstances)

I don't see enabling of get/put, but I'm no compiler crack, so I might have missed that. You can test that yourself. (whoops on rereading your post, you already did).

So I think the answer is primarily lookahead with the ^ operator.

**added later response from Pascaldragon **

A Pascal developer more into dialectal items finally reacted, which I quote here verbatim:

> Put and Get are not part of modeswitch ISOIO, because they're not intrinsics and are instead provided by the ISO7185 unit which is only used for modeswitch ISO. As that unit also contains functionality that's not covered by the ISOIO modeswitch (some types, Round functions) it's not used for that modeswitch, but only together with the mode.

So basically the implementation is a library thing, and can't easily be decoupled from the other library based ISO stuff.

Comment: Yes thank you!  I just discovered that the filetype^ pointer was enabled with the switch. You are calling it lookahead. I think I understand. The pointer now looks ahead, not what is stored in a file buffer. To move ahead in the file, an actual read is performed. How would that work with write? if I write to the filetype pointer, how do I move past to the next item?

Comment: As to why am I trying to do this, I am porting ISO code, specifically the P5 interpreter, into another project that compiles in objFPC. Thinking maybe to simulate a put, I would read the file pointer back then do a write().

Comment: I've no idea, but I can ask on the maillistwhy get/put is not under isoio.  Note that dialect is a per unit decision. Another possible solution is to keep the ISO code in a separate unit.module, and call it from the objfpc one.